# Extracting tag attr 'data-title' beautifulsoup4

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Trying to extract every div tag with data-title and data-url attr.

Would prefer a code to create a list like:
for data-title
[TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4]

for data-url
[urltest1, urltest2, urltest3, urltest4]

Sample data (bs4 format parsed)

```
<div id="container">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('li').live('click', function(e){
    window.location = $(this).find('.widget').data('url');
  });
});
</script>
<div class="gridster">
<ul>
<li data-col="1" data-row="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
<div data-title="TEST1" data-url="/urltest1" data-view="Text"></div>
</li>
<li data-col="2" data-row="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
<div data-title="TEST2" data-url="/urltest2" data-view="Text"></div>
</li>
<li data-col="3" data-row="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
<div data-title="TEST3" data-url="/urltest3" data-view="Text"></div>
</li>
<li data-col="15" data-row="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
<div data-title="TEST4" data-url="/urltest4" data-view="Text"></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

```
$('div[data-title]').each(function() {
    // Here is the div with the attribute data-title
});
```